# Navbar в слайдере

Tags: html, вёрстка, slider, bootstrap4, navigationbar

Каким способом можно `navbar` вытянуть на слайдер поверх его??? Чтобы под ним фон менялся, а сам `navbar`оставался там же
Смотрел [сайт](https://htmlforum.io/topic/59657-kak-pomestit-menyu-na-slayder-bootstrap-4/?tab=comments#comment-388525)
У него была такая же проблема, но он не исправил её. Мой код сейчас в точности как и его, только без css. 
[image: Макет хедера]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Можно

```
header {
    margin-bottom: -60px; /* или сколько необходимо */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Ну и в верстке

```
<header></header>
<main class="slider"></main>
```

Comment: ничего не меняется

Comment: хедер не должен быть в слайдере, слайдер не должен быть в хедере. отдельные блоки.